# Eclipse no longer displays compile error badges

Tags: java, eclipse

The compile error badges have stopped showing up on my source files  but still display at the project level (see screen shot below). They used to show up for me, but since this morning, they've stopped displaying as they usually do. The exact compile error still shows in the Problems view, but there is no quick way to determine at a glance from the Package Explorer view.

I've looked through the Key Binding preferences trying to find a key binding that might toggle the display of the badges, but didn't see anything. Likewise, the Java file type badging preferences don't seem have have anything relevant either.

Anyone have an idea where the preference for showing/hiding the compile error badge might be located at?

[image: Annotated Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a red 'X' at the topmost level - on "HealthInMotion". So your package explorer has not stopped showing badges.

Could it be that there is a very severe error that is taking precedence over everything else?
Something with the buildpath perhaps?
Try thinking on those lines. Look in detail in the "Markers" pane. Perhaps something is listed there.

(And, as always, Do a `Project --> clean`, close and open eclipse :-)

[Added]
Hey wait - your package `com.digitalenginesoftware.healthinmotion` is white in color. Its disabled, hidden or something like that?
Or, not part of build path (excluded?)

Comment: I've already done a clean, so no good there. As for the white package, I'm using the Google Web Toolkit plugin, and its always been that way as far as I remember. Even with using the GWT plugin, the errors were displaying, just not anymore.

Comment: You can also do the close/reopen project instead of terminating Eclipse.

Comment: @Nivas your question "Could it be that there is a very severe error that is taking precedence over everything else?" was right on. I accidentally deleted a jar that the build was dependent on, which was causing the build to fail at that step and never make it to the error I was expecting to see displayed. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and was able to resolve it by looking for any major config error. In my case a path for a linked resource was missing.

Comment: This is helpful, but make sure to realize that the post was answered two years ago and has an accepted answer already. If you want you can comment on such posts, but don't give a completely new, simple answer!

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue where Java compiler errors weren't showing up in 'Package Explorer' with the red X.  I took Nivas advice and looked for bigger errors and found that another project had a buildpath error.  Once I corrected that error, Eclipse picked up on the smaller compiler problems.  Thanks Nivas.

Hope this helps out anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted all the projects from eclipse and imported them again. Crude way, but it worked.